# Fetch data from textfield and display it in another textfield

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

```
//combo box actionperformed method.

private void CmbActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
//created aray of objects

    JTextField t[]=new JTextField[8];

    String num=null,s1;
    int num1=0;
    num=Cmb.getSelectedItem().toString();
    num1=Integer.parseInt(num);
    //applied a logic to create same no. of textfields that selected in combo box.   

    while(num1!=0){ 
        for(int i=0;i<num1;i++)
        {
            t[i]=new JTextField(10);
            jPanel2.add(t[i]);
            b1.setText("the objects has created");
            jPanel2.revalidate();
            validate();
            num1--;
        }
    }
}
//actionperformed method of buuton b1.
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    String a1;
    a1=t1.getText();

    //getting error t1 not found;
    //I think it is because t1 is local aray of comboactionperformedmethod and cant be accessed by this method. I need ur help to solve this. 

    b1.setText(s1);  
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem and provide [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to declare your text area fields as class member variables, not inside the method. The other methods inside that class can then access them.

```
JTextField t[]=new JTextField[8];
//created aray of objects

private void CmbActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
```

Then:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    String a1;
    a1=t[0].getText();
```

Note also the correct way to access the members of the array.

Comment: you are saying to create a method inside a method?..can you explain me by edit my code.

Comment: @AdityaSoni You need to read up and **understand** exactly what methods, classes, local variables and member variables are. Once you understand those 4 things the solution will be obvious.

Comment: yaa i got your point ..i have declared textfield array as class member(outside the method) but then also t1.getText() is getting empty string.. and T1.setText() is showing empty string in textfield b1.